# clicking JS popup close button refreshes page and displays popup again

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, addeventlistener

I want the page to show popup when its loaded or refreshed. Upon clicking close button, popup should disappear and show me the page below. However, my code refreshes the page and displays popup again when I click close. How can I Fix this?

```js
var popupDisplayed = "false" // localStorage.getItem("popupDisplayed");
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (popupDisplayed !== "true") {
    var popupOverlay = document.getElementById('popup-overlay');
    var popupGreeting = document.getElementById('popup-greeting');

    popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
    popupGreeting.style.display = 'none';

    setTimeout(function() {
      popupOverlay.style.display = 'block';
      popupGreeting.style.display = 'block';
    }, 1000); // Reduced the delay to 1 second for demonstration purposes

    //localStorage.setItem("popupDisplayed", "true");
  }
});

document.querySelector("#closeButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var popupOverlay = document.getElementById('popup-overlay');
  var popupGreeting = document.getElementById('popup-greeting');

  popupOverlay.style.display = 'none';
  popupGreeting.style.display = 'none';

  popupOverlay.style.opacity = '0';
  popupGreeting.style.opacity = '0';
});
```

```css
#popup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 9999;
}

#popup-greeting {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-overlay"></div>
<div id="popup-greeting">
  <button id="closeButton">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: We need a proper [mre] from you, not just snippets that lack context. _Guess_ - is your button part of a form? Then it will _submit_ that form when clicked; you'd need to either prevent the event default action in your click handler, or add `type="button"` to your button, to make it a click button instead of a submit button.

Comment: Click [edit], then `[<>]` the snippet editor and give us a [mcve] with relevant HTML, CSS, JS and frameworks from CDN

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for your reply but my pop is not a result of form. The popup should display upon page load. I have created a MRE as you have asked. Looking forward to your answers

Comment: @mplungjan I have modified the question with MRE as asked

Comment: localStorage doesn't work here in the snippet; and when I put your code into a jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/xzy75cs2/, the close button is not even clickable.

Comment: @Teemu, I tried your suggestion, but it makes the cancel button not work.

Comment: This becomes even more odd ... Are you using a framework, or is there a library involved in pop-up creation?  Even when we'd remove the overlay, your code doesn't behave like you've described. Maybe there's another click listener attached to the button too ..?

Comment: We cannot click the button because the overlay in in front of it

Comment: @mplungjan button works when the overlay is removed in test environment. How odd. I donot have this issue on my dev server

Comment: @Teemu Im using sharepoint on prem dev server. There is currently no library involved in popup creation. if i remove the overlay in my enironment. it behaves even weird. It refreshes the page without me having to click the button. There is no other clicker attached as far as my knowledge

Comment: "as far as you know" - Perhaps you have an ad blocker or another browser plugin that messes with the page. Perhaps you have a sharepoint script replacing yours. Perhaps debug the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! --

I used jquery to hide the popup, removed local storage and used prevent default function to solve the issue

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    
    var popupOverlay = document.getElementById('popup-overlay');
    var popupGreeting = document.getElementById('popup-greeting'); 
    var closeButton = document.getElementById('closeButton');

    popupOverlay.style.display = 'block';
    popupGreeting.style.display = 'block';
    
    document.querySelector("#closeButton").addEventListener("click", function(){    
       
       
        event.preventDefault();
        
        $("#popup-overlay").hide("slow");
        $("#popup-greeting").hide("slow");
        $("#closeButton").hide("slow");     
 }
 
 );
 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add button attribute 'type="button"' or you can also used 'e.preventDefault()' to stop page refresh.

```html
<button type="button">
```

Comment: First of all, you're not using JS but jQuery. Next, your code is far from being complete and missing fundamentals. Last but not least, adding `type="button"` on a button will do nothing.

Comment: currently, I can just recommend waiting and reading the comments of the question. The issue seems not to be reproducible.

Comment: @TheCoder, prevent deafult function was part  of the solution and its solved! thank you